# How to remove all chars not include in a regex

Tags: php

I would like to remove all characters that do not match a specified Regex.

for example

```
$a = "hello my name is ,pate !";

echo notin_replace("[a-zA-Z]","",$a);

hello my name is pate
```

Comment: While I disagree with the tone of some of the comments here, I agree with the sentiment - searching would serve you well. Here is a SO question about Regex that would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world, and here is a beginner's article on Regex replacement in PHP: http://www.webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^a-zA-Z]`

Mind the carret at the beginning of the character class. It means not.

```
$a = "hello my name is ,pate !";

echo preg_replace("([^a-zA-Z ])", "", $a);

hello my name is pate
```

Don't forget to add space as well to the allowed characters, otherwise it would be removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z ]/i', '', $a); // the /i is for case-insensitive
                                    // put a space inside the expression
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_replace` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/function.preg-replace.php))

```
<?php
$string = 'hello my name is ,pate !';
// this patter allows all alpha chars and whitespace (tabs, spaces, linebreaks)
$pattern = '/[^a-zA-Z\s]/i';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>
```

Try it on codepaste.org: http://codepad.org/ZoqcvtIu

Comment: You use the `i` modifier while putting small and large letters within the character class. Is the modifier for a reason?

Comment: you response is correct but I had to choose one so I took the first one. Thanks